# Trigger method when all service calls complete

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that makes two calls to a service to get 2 sets of data.

I want my component to show data based on logic that requires the data from both calls.

How do I make my method that processes the data trigger when both the service requests return an observable?

This is what I have so far:

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    //get message contents
    this._pageSpeedService.getMessageData()
            .subscribe(results => this.messageData = <TestResultMessageLogic[]>results,
                       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    //get data to show what messages to show
    this._pageSpeedService.getResults(this.testUrl)
            .subscribe(results => this.testResults = results,
                       error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}

processApiRespone(testResults: IPageSpeedResult, messageData: TestResultMessageLogic[]): void{
    this.testResults = testResults;
    this.alerts = [];

    for(let testLogic of messageData)
    {
        // .. logic is here, omitted for brevity

        this.alerts.concat(builtData);
    }
```

So when I have `this.messageData` & `this.testResults` with returned data, I then need to run `processApiRespone()` in order to create `this.alerts` which I iterate over in my view template.

What mechanism should I use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to forkJoin, you can also use Observable.combineLatest.

**The imports:**

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';
```

**And using the operator:**

```
Observable.combineLatest(this._pageSpeedService.getMessageData, 
                    this._pageSpeedService.getResults(this.testUrl))
     .subscribe(result => {
             this.messageData = result[0];
             this.testResults = result[1];

             //now process the response
             this.processApiResponse(this.testResults, this.messageData);
      });
```

Observable.combineLatest takes two or more source observables, and will emit its first value when at all of the observables have emitted at least one value. The combined value that is emitted is an array of all the last values emitted from each of the source observables.

[See the RxJS documentation for combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html)

With your example of dealing with single emitting observables, there's no big difference between the two operators, but combineLatest seems to be more useful overall as a handy operator to have in your pocket.

Comment: This looks ideal for my purpose.  What do I need to import to make static call to combineLatest?  I couldn't tell from the documentation and `Observable` isn't defined in my scope.

Comment: Many thanks.  Does the documentation show the namespaces?  Working out the imports for RxJs is confusing me right now.

Comment: FYI, i'd strongly recommend WebStorm for development with Angular especially, but Typescript in general. It's not that costly an IDE and typescript's main benefit is in better tooling, which WebStorm takes advantage of

Comment: as an example, with the exception of rxjs which has truly weird imports, i never write typescript import statements anymore - webstorm manages those for me completely.

Comment: RxJS imports really are weird, although there is a method to their madness. All of their operators can be added by using the format: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/<operator-name>` for operators that work on observable instances and  `import 'rxjs/add/observable/<operator-name>` for operators that work off of the main Observable type. As for the classes, they can usually be imported from `rxjs/<ClassName>`   (eg. `import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject' )

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I've tried a few editors and none have had very good tooling for angular.  I will consider webstorm (I already own phpstorm, not sure if that has the same tooling).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `forkJoin` operator if you have to observables that only emit a single result (e.g. a http call)

```
Observable.forkJoin(this._pageSpeedService.getMessageData, 
                    this._pageSpeedService.getResults(this.testUrl))
     .subscribe(result => {
             this.messageData = result[0];
             this.testResults = result[1];

             //now process the response
             this.processApiResponse(this.testResults, this.messageData);
      });
```

We've used this in our project to wait for a number of http calls (while showing a spinner/loading UI) when loading a page.

See [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) for operator documentation.